# Airflow BranchPythonOperator not executing one branch

Tags: python, airflow

Other postings on this/similar issue haven't helped me. So I fear I'm overlooking something obvious, but here goes. Several Airflow DAGs in my setup uses the BranchPythonOperator, one of which never executes a particular branch. Here's the relevant code:

```
def check_transport():
   date = datetime.today().day;
   if date == 15 or date == 16:
       return 'skip_transport'
   else:
       return 'transport_data'

transport_data = BashOperator(
    task_id = 'transport_data',
    bash_command = '**Bash command to transport data is here and correct**',
    dag = dag)

skip_transport = DummyOperator(
    task_id = 'skip_transport',
    dag = dag)

transport_check = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id = 'transport_check',
    python_callable = check_transport,
    dag = dag)
transport_check.set_downstream(transport_data)
transport_check.set_downstream(skip_transport)
```

The tree view of the DAG shows on 01/15 it correctly followed the skip_transport branch, marking it a success and marking transport_data as skipped. The other days shows skip_transport as skipped and transport_data white (no status) and that branch isn't executed.

The log of the transport_check shows that it is intending to do the correct actions:

```
[2019-01-30 07:44:17,786] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2019-01-30 07:44:17,786] {models.py:1342} INFO - Executing <Task(BranchPythonOperator): transport_check> on 2019-01-29 03:30:00
[2019-01-30 07:44:17,835] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2019-01-30 07:44:17,835] {python_operator.py:81} INFO - Done. Returned value was: transport_data
[2019-01-30 07:44:17,835] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2019-01-30 07:44:17,835] {python_operator.py:106} INFO - Following branch transport_data
[2019-01-30 07:44:17,836] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2019-01-30 07:44:17,835] {python_operator.py:107} INFO - Marking other directly downstream tasks as skipped
[2019-01-30 07:44:17,861] {base_task_runner.py:95} INFO - Subtask: [2019-01-30 07:44:17,861] {python_operator.py:119} INFO - Done.
```

I have tried adding `trigger_rule = "all_done"` to the PythonBranchOperator with no change in behavior.

Comment: While it won't solve your problem, logically, shouldn't `trigger_rule="all_done"` be set to your `transport_data` / `skip_transport` tasks instead of `transport_check` task?

Comment: Admittedly, that's something I've been unclear about. I can make that modification and see how it works tonight.

Comment: There was no change in behavior after adding the trigger rule to the `transport_data` and `skip_transport` tasks.